# Web application with QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, web-gis

I am using QGIS to create maps using CSV files. I want to create a web application where the base map would be first displayed.

I want the users to have dropdowns lists which would be populated with the table attribute values. When the user selects a value from the dropdown a new query would be sent to server and a new layer would then be created on the base map which would be sent back to the client.

Basically I want to learn how do I:

1. Fetch table attribute values dynamically to web page from QGIS map/shapefile.
2. Populate those values in respective dropdown lists.
3. Fire a query to the server where the base map/shapefile resides which the generates a new layer and sends in back to client.

How do I approach this?

I want to code the web app using JavaScript and server using Python.

Comment: The approach I suggest using this site will be to choose the software you wish to test first and then focus on whether and how it may be able to meet your first requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Qgis has a Qgis2web plugin that can make a web map out of a project. This map is static, what you are looking for is a dynamic web map so you are better off using web app builder like opengeosuite or geonode. QGIS is more powerful on desktop and analysis side but weaker in web app making.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the direction. Would I require to use a mapping server too? For e.g. something like GeoServer?

Comment: Both of those has geoserver builtin. you don't need anything else.